# Using Ability class in Rails Engine

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan

I have a engine inside the lib folder named Support. In that folder, I have a `Ticket` controller.

I have created an ability class in the main app and I'm trying to manage all the models for the admin role. When I call the `Tickets` controller, it throws the error:

`NameError in Support::TicketsController#index uninitialized constant Ticket`

The **app/model/ability.rb** file is:

```
class Ability 
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.role? == :admin
      can :manage , :all
    end
  end
end
```

The **lib/support/tickets_controller.rb** file is:

```
module Support
  class TicketsController < Support::ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource
    respond_to :html, :xml, :json

    def index
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the model class is namespaced differently than the controller, you will need to specify the `:class` option.

```
module Support
  class TicketsController < ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource :class => Support::Ticket
  end
end
```